# window.openDatabase is not a function error in moodle 3.8 Ionic app

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, moodle-mobile

I am trying to customize Moodle 3.8 mobile app, I want it to have logos and splash screen that is personalized to my brand. I have cloned the repo from `https://github.com/moodlehq/moodlemobile2.git` into my ubuntu 18.04 machine and run `npm install setup` on the moodleapp project root directory. I am running `Ionic CLI 5.2.5`. After the `npm install setup` is done successfully, I then run `ionic serve --lab` or even with a --lab flag to see my app in my firefox browser. The command executes the app without an error and initializes the app in the browser but here is where the problem comes, the app is blank and nothing is displayed besides just a dark screen.

I head over to inspect the element and found that there is an error that says `"window.openDatabase is not a function"`. The Moodle mobile app 3.8 have offline data storage capabilities using SQLite db which I am suspecting as the error source so I installed `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage` and `npm install @ionic-native/sqlite` into the project but nothing changes. I have been researching for that error for days now but no proper source to the problem and solution. The full error is:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: window.openDatabase is not a function ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: "window.openDatabase is not a function"
    init sqlitedb.ts:152
    SQLiteDB sqlitedb.ts:144
    SQLiteDBMock sqlitedb.ts:31
    getDB db.ts:45
    CoreAppProvider app.ts:78
    Angular 8
    invoke polyfills.js:3
    onInvoke Angular
    invoke polyfills.js:3
    run polyfills.js:3
    Angular 3
    invoke polyfills.js:3
    run polyfills.js:3
    f polyfills.js:3
    invokeTask polyfills.js:3
    runTask polyfills.js:3
    o polyfills.js:3
 SQLiteDBMock.prototype.init@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:135760:26
SQLiteDB@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:104930:14
SQLiteDBMock@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:135647:28
CoreDbProvider.prototype.getDB@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:83056:42
CoreAppProvider@http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:4415:30
_createClass@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11317:20
_createProviderInstance$1@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11281:26
initNgModule@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:11234:28
NgModuleRef_@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12489:21
createNgModuleRef@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:12478:12
debugCreateNgModuleRef@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14812:12
NgModuleFactory_.prototype.create@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15950:25
PlatformRef.prototype.bootstrapModuleFactory/<@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5876:78
F</l</t.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14976
onInvoke@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5134:33
F</l</t.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14916
F</c</r.prototype.run@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10143
NgZone.prototype.run@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:4951:69
PlatformRef.prototype.bootstrapModuleFactory@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5874:23
PlatformRef.prototype.bootstrapModule/<@http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5953:59
F</l</t.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14976
F</c</r.prototype.run@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10143
f/<@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20242
F</l</t.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15660
F</c</r.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10834
o@http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7894
polyfills.js:3:20723
    onUnhandledError http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3
    r http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3
    microtaskDrainDone http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3
    microtaskDrainDone http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3
    o http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3

​
```

​I am stuck on this, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still stuck on this but just in case others have the same problem: this behavior seems to be linked to using firefox. Using chromium-browser does not throw this exception.

The moodle mobile debelopment team *recommends* [using chromium](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Moodle_Mobile_development_using_Chrome_or_Chromium) for desktop development, though they should probably say it is **required**.